# Is There a Better/Faster Way to Code for "IsNot Nothing" in Linq-to-XML?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I deal with a lot of XML for transformations. I typically find that I spend most of my time doing something like this:

```
Dim elem1 = doc.<bignode>.<smallnode>.SingleOrDefault
If elem1 IsNot Nothing Then
    ''# do my transformation
End If
```

Or

```
Dim attr1 = doc.<bignode>.<smallnode>.@attribute1
If attr1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso attr1 <> "1" Then
    ''# do my transformation
End If
```

I have like a zillion of these things that check for the existence of an element or attribute and then only if it exists will I do something.

I suppose that is okay, but I'm just wondering if there is some better way of handling this where I `Dim` the element or attribute and then start processing for my transformation, if the element is not there it will just silently and gracefully fail and move on to the next thing in my code.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an extension method to handle the `IsNot Nothing` check in a more fluent manner:

```
<Extension()>
Sub SafeTransform(ByVal element As XElement, ByVal transform As Action(Of XElement))
  If element IsNot Nothing Then
    transform(element)
  End If
End Sub
```

You will have to define the transformation as a separate method:

```
Sub Transform(ByVal element As XElement) As XElement
  '' # do my transformation
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
doc.<bignode>.<smallnode>.SingleOrDefault.SafeTransform(AddressOf Transform)
```

You can also use a lambda expression:

```
Dim transform As Action(Of XElement) = Sub(element)
  '' # do my transformation
End Sub
doc.<bignode>.<smallnode>.SingleOrDefault.SafeTransform(transform)
```

These transformations are subroutines and not functions. If you instead want to return transformed `XElement` objects you should really look into [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx).

Here is a silly LINQ to XML example:

```
Dim doc As XDocument =
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Big>
  <Small Name="Foo"/>
  <Other Name="Bar"/>
</Big>

Dim transformedDoc = new XDocument( _
  new XElement( _
    doc.Root.Name,
    doc.Root.Elements.Select( _
      Function(element) _
        If(element.Name = "Small", new XElement("Transformed", element.Attributes()), element))))
```

This is the transformed XML:

```
<Big>
  <Transformed Name="Foo"/>
  <Other Name="Bar"/>
</Big>
```

Comment: perfect, lots of great examples here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y666)? Instead of iterating over nodes you could create a LINQ query that omits null values. You would then iterate over a filtered set sparing you the `IsNot Nothing` checks.

Comment: I kind of have looked at it. It sounds like it would be `doc.<bignode>.Where(Function(e) e.SingleOrDefault.Name = "smallnode")` or some such logic. Is that what you're thinking?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, checking for existence in this manner is your best bet. IMO, it's good defensive programming, and how I handle it on day to day basis.  Even when I'm actively excluding NULL values (or providing them a default value) I'll always check for existence.

Comment: interesting point - i thought i was the only one :)  actually, i didn't term it "defensive programming", i termed it "a lot of code" :)